# How can I transform a list to a recursive dictionary with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, recursion

I have lists containing ordered keys:

```
var dict = {};
var list = ['0', '0', '0', '1'];
```

I would like to use `list` to create a recursive dictionary like below:

```
dict = {
    "0": {
        "0": {
            "0": {
                "1": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the length of the list vary from 1 to more, I'm struggling to understand how I can actually do that since I don't understand how I can assign multiple keys inside each others using Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Right now this reads like "please code this for me." Instead, do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a variable that will point to the current place in the tree:

```js
var dict = {};
var list = ['0', '0', '0', '1'];
var current = dict;
list.forEach(function(k, i) {
  current = current[k] = {};
});

console.log(dict);
```

Another option is [`Array.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to iterate the `list` backwards, build a top level, assign the result to a lower level, and so on...

```js
const list = ['0', '0', '0', '1'];

const dict = list.reduceRight((r, k) => ({ [k]: r }), {});

console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cleverly use `Array.prototype.reduce` with simple property assignment

```js
const dict = {}
const list = ['0', '0', '0', '1']

list.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] = {}, dict);

console.log (dict)
// {"0":{"0":{"0":{"1":{}}}}}
```

Thats basically the short version of looping through all the keys and using an accumulator to store the current position in the tree:

```
  let acc = dict;

  for(const key of list) {
    acc = acc[key] = {};
  }
```

Comment: @t.j. i dont have the cool `<>` button on my mobile device, and i cant remember the snippet markdown :)

Comment: I helped you out by adding a snippet from my desktop :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're coming from Python. JavaScript does not have dictionaries (`dict`) like Python and instead has objects. Some of the operations provided by Python make it easy to work with dynamic keys but may be more difficult in JavaScript. Until we know what you'd be doing with this, it's hard to advise you further.

Anyway, you can accomplish your goal with a simple recursive function

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const toDict = ([ first = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
  first === Empty
    ? {}
    : { [first] : toDict (rest) }

console.log (toDict (['0', '0', '0', '1']))
// {
//   "0": {
//     "0": {
//       "0": {
//         "1": {}
//       }
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create recursive function that will loop array and add properties to your object until end of array.

```js
var dict = {};
var list = ['0', '0', '0', '1'];

const f = (o, a, n = 0) => a[n] && f(o[a[n]] = {}, a, n+1)
 
f(dict, list)
console.log(dict)
```